# Hosting connected apps from developer account

Tags: connected-apps, developer-edition

From Salesforce documentation it seems that a Developer account is the proper place to run / "host" my Connected App indefinitely, for production usage.

Is that accurate, is that what others do?

My concern would be if developer accounts are seen as something that Salesforce can enable / disable at their will, not meant for any sort of Production reliance.

I understand that the use of a Developer account as your company's CRM can get you shut down. But I want to be clear on whether or not it is OK for it to "host" the production instance of a Connected App that handles oAuth flow for rest api access to other Salesforce organizations.

Appreciate any insight into proper usage from veterans - it's only because of a pro here that I realized you don't need to distribute connected apps.